# Job DSL - How to configure postBuildSteps for maven to kick off only if build is successful

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

Is there way in job dsl to configure postBuildSteps only if build succeeds, for a maven job. I saw there is postSuccessfulBuildSteps which applies only to release job.

Comment: Are you effectively saying that you want to dynamically reconfigure the job whilst it is running?  You want to run the "maven" step, if that succeeds trigger the dsl to add a subsequent step which then runs?

Comment: no. Jenkins provides way to do post builds actions only if build is successful

Comment: OK I think I understand;  You want to use Job-DSL to create a maven job with a PostBuildAction.  The PostBuildAction part must be configured to  run only if  the maven step is successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a "configure" block to append "custom" `<runPostStepsIfResult>` settings into the config.xml

This works for me:

```
job(type: Maven) {
    name('MyMavenJob')
    goals('install')

    preBuildSteps {
        shell('#!/bin/bash\n' +
              'echo "PRE BUILD SCRIPT"\n' +
              'env | sort\n' +
              'echo "PRE BUILD END"\n')
    }
    
    postBuildSteps {
        shell('#!/bin/bash\n' +
              'echo "POST BUILD SCRIPT"\n' +
              'env | sort\n' +
              'echo "POST BUILD END"\n')
    }

    // Append <runPostStepsIfResult> at the end of the xml
    //    (which will be just after the closing </postbuilders> tag)
    // "it" is a groovy.util.Node representing the
    //    root <project> element of config.xml.
    configure { it <<
        'runPostStepsIfResult' {
            name('SUCCESS')
        }
    }
}
```

In general if you need to add XML which is not supported by Job DSL you can find out what you need by manually configuring a job in Jenkins, then looking at the resultant `config.xml` for that job on the Jenkins-master disk. This is usually located at `${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/job-name/config.xml`

The job-dsl playground at http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/ is a useful place to test changes until you're getting something which matches what Jenkins does in the job/job-name/config.xml file when set manually.

**2022 Update**

There are methods now available to handle this case without the complexity of a `configure` block:

- [postSuccessfulBuildSteps](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.wrapper.ReleaseContext.postSuccessfulBuildSteps)
- [postFailedBuildSteps](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.wrapper.ReleaseContext.postFailedBuildSteps)

The code above does not appear to compile anymore in the [job-dsl playground](http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/) due to other API changes.  With the following modification it does compile however:

```
mavenJob("example") {
    description('MyMavenJob')
    goals('install')

    preBuildSteps {
        shell('#!/bin/bash\n' +
              'echo "PRE BUILD SCRIPT"\n' +
              'env | sort\n' +
              'echo "PRE BUILD END"\n')
    }

    postBuildSteps {
        shell('#!/bin/bash\n' +
              'echo "POST BUILD SCRIPT"\n' +
              'env | sort\n' +
              'echo "POST BUILD END"\n')
    }

    // Append <runPostStepsIfResult> at the end of the xml
    //    (which will be just after the closing </postbuilders> tag)
    // "it" is a groovy.util.Node representing the
    //    root <project> element of config.xml.
    configure { it <<
        'runPostStepsIfResult' {
            name('SUCCESS')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's strange but it didn't work with `postBuilders` but started to work with `postbuilders` (in lower case). I've tests it on jenkins-1.596.2

Comment: @Slava You're right it should have been lower-case, I'm on 1.596.2 also.  
I noticed that the "Run only if build succeeds" radio is no longer set, the "runPostStepsIfResult" block should actually be appended _after_ the <postbuilders> tag, not within it.   I've amended the example accordingly.

Comment: Is this still up-to-date?

Comment: @Angi2412 updated for 2022

Comment: @EdRandall thanks for the update. but when i do:
`configure { node ->
        node << 'runPostStepsIfResult' {
          name('SUCCESS')
          ordinal('0')
          color('BLUE')
          completeBuild('true')
        }
      }`
it shows `CannotResolveClassException: runPostStepsIfResult` in the latest jenkins version. Any ideas?

Comment: @Angi2412 sorry no idea, I am not using Jenkins anymore & can only go on the playground behaviour.   Maybe it's been removed from the API - in which case just use one of the 2 new methods (depending on what you need to achieve), and drop the configure block altogether

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
postBuildSteps("SUCCESS") {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use conditional step plugin ( https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin)?

Comment: You miss read my question, I was asking about 'way in **job dsl** to configure postBuildSteps only if build succeeds'